# Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

This question has been asked before but I did not solve my problem and I getting some weird functionality.

If I put my `index.html` file in the static directory like so:

[image]

I get the following error in my browser:

[image]

And in my console:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "login": 
Exception parsing document: template="login", line 6 - column 3
2015-08-11 16:09:07.922 ERROR 5756 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] 
in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception 
parsing document: template="login", line 6 - column 3] with root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "meta" must be terminated by 
the matching end-tag "</meta>".
```

However if I move my index.html file into the templates directory I get the following error in my browser:
[image]

[image]

I have added my view resolvers:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/results").setViewName("results");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/form").setViewName("form");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Person person) {
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }
        return "redirect:/results";
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        //resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta>
    <meta> charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>

<a href="../../login.html"><span>Click here to move to the next page</span></a>

</body>

</html>
```

At this point I do not know what is going on. Can anyone give me some advice?

## Update

I missed a typo in `index.html`, but I am still getting the same errors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta> charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>

<a href="../../login.html"><span>Click here to move to the next page</span></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the console is telling you that is a conflict with login. I think that you should declare also in the `index.html` Thymeleaf. Something like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>k</title> 
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution was so difficult to find :)

Answer (score 30):

Check for the name of the

> templates

folder. it should be templates not template(without s).

Comment: u saved my day. I had a spelling mistake in the templates folder name

Answer (score 25):

`index.html` should be inside `templates`, as I know. So, your second attempt looks correct.

But, as the error message says, `index.html` looks like having some errors. E.g. the in the third line, the `meta` tag should be actually `head` tag, I think.

Comment: please see update. I fixed it but I am still getting the same error. The index.html file is currently in the templates directory.

Comment: Yes your meta tag is messed up: 
    <meta> charset="UTF-8">

Comment: This answer helped me realize I closed my `<head>` tag with `/>` by accident.

Answer (score 24):

I am new to spring spent an hour trying to figure this out.

go to   --- >  **`application.properties`**

add these :

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Answer (score 10):

this can be resolved by copying the below code in application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 7):

this make me success!

```
prefix: classpath:/templates/
```

check  your application.yml

Answer (score 5):

If you are facing this issue and everything looks good, try invalidate cache/restart from your IDE. This will resolve the issue in most of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

The error message might also occur, if the template name starts with a **leading slash**:

```
return "/index";
```

In the IDE the file was resolved successfully with a path with two slashes:

```
getResource(templates//index.html)
 Delegating to parent classloader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@2399ee45
 --> Returning 'file:/Users/andreas/git/my-project/frontend/out/production/resources/templates//index.html'
```

On the productive system, where the template is **packed into** a jar, the resolution with two slashes does not work and leads to the same error message.

✅ Omit the leading slash:

```
return "index";
```

Comment: This is a great answer. More on why the consecutive slashes work in IDE but fail via JAR: [https://bilalkaun.com/2022/04/20/why-consecutive-slashes-fail-in-jar-files/](https://bilalkaun.com/2022/04/20/why-consecutive-slashes-fail-in-jar-files/)

Answer (score 3):

this error probably is occurred most of the time due to missing closing tag. and further you can the following dependency to resolve this issue while supporting legacy HTML formate.

as it your code      charset="UTF-8"> here is no closing for meta tag.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
<artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
<version>1.9.22</version>                                 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was because of Case sensitivity. I was using `~{fragments/Base}` instead of `~{fragments/base}` (The name of the file was `base.html`)

My development environment was windows but the server hosting the application was Linux so I was not seeing this issue during development since windows' paths are not case sensitive.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had the exact same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5` in the application.properties worked for me. You could try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced `TemplateResolver` view error , Adding the  `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5` in the `application.properties` worked for me. In case of build created in STS and running for Websphere 9 ..

Answer (score 1):

Check the html file is available in src/main/resources/templates folder

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @RestController as well,
I was facing this same problem, i added both @RestController @Controller, it worked find

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions here and none of them seemed to be working for me
So I tried changing the return statement a little bit and it worked!
Seems like the issue with thymleaf not being able to recognize the template file, adding  ".html" in the return statement seemed to fix this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage(){
        return "index.html";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I meet this error I check if my target view folder is inside `/src/man/.../resources/templates` and if I am not making any typo.

Answer (score 0):

It May be due to some exceptions like (Parsing NUMERIC to String or vise versa).

Please verify cell values either are null or do handle Exception and see.

Best,
Shahid

Answer (score 0):

**I wasted 2 hours debugging this issue.**

Althought I had the template file in the right location (within resources/templates/), I kept getting the same error.

It turns out it was because I had created some extra packages in my project. For instance, all controller files were in 'controller' package.

I did the same thing for the files which were automatically generated by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io).

I don't understand exactly why this happens,

but when I moved the `ServletInitializer` file and the one annotated with  `@SpringBootApplication` back to the root of the project, **the error went away !**

Answer (score 0):

For me, including these in the pom.xml CAUSES the exception. Removing it from the pom.xml resolves the issue.
(Honestly, I don't know how that happen)

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
           <includes>
               <include>application.properties</include>
           </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had everything else right as suggested above but still it was complaining that "template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers". On comparing my project with some other sample projects which were working fine, I figured out I was missing

```
<configuration>
    <addResources>true</addResources>
</configuration>
```

in spring-boot-maven-plugin. Adding which worked for me. So my plugins section now looks like

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I am not sure why I needed to add  tag to get thymeleaf working though.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have forgot to end the tag  as <meta .... /> or using </meta

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by removing the "/" from the path of html file.

before:  **return "/shopView/index.html";**

after:  **return "shopView/index.html";**

Answer (score 0):

check your static and templates copy to **target** directory at the build. If not issue is in pom.xml which exclude copying those files.

First, manually copy and paste those two directories to target directory and check, if works check pom.xml file .

This solve my issue.