# Thymeleaf can't find index template

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I get the error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible
>   by any of the configured Template Resolvers

This project contains only an IndexController and the index.html which is located  `resources/templates/index.html`

Here's an image of the resource folder structure:

[image]

This is the method within the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944355/error-resolving-template-index-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be-acces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mapping them separately and see if that resolves the issue. Try the following for index.

```
  @GetMapping("index")
    public String getIndex(){
        return "index"; 
    }
```

As you can see, I changed the methods name from index to getIndex which makes more sense, naming wise.

Comment: B.Still getting the same error with that code. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Still nothing.. So weird, i've done a few projects before this with zero issues..

Comment: Could you post the content of your index.html ?

Comment: `<html lang="en" class="k-webkit k-webkit43">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Index</h1>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Your first HTML tag should point to thymeleaf. It should look like this:
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

Comment: Accidentally removed that earlier, but it didn't seem to matter when adding it back. This is odd as i've had plenty of other projects work perfectly.

Comment: If your project does not have a lot of code, could you post it all and I will replicate that on my computer to see what is going on ?

Comment: Well, that works just fine on my end. I was able to easily access / /index and /home without any issues... Try a different browser...check your spellings...clear cash...restart your IDE...See if that helps ?

Comment: the issue was the resource folder was in java->com instead of on the same level as the java folder.. what a day. Thanks so much for helping me out a lot

Comment: If you think my answer could help future searchers, please upvote it and mark it as correct. I am glad it got solved out !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you configuring your Thmeleaf beans, but in oder to use templates located on your templates folder, you should have a similar configuration like the one below.

```
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    // Set prefix should do the trick.
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Also, if I am not mistaken, by default the resource package is used as the based folder, so if you add templates, before the /index, it should work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
public String index(){
    return "templates/index";
}
```

Comment: Do you mind adding your beans configuration? This has to do with Spring not being able to find the resource.

Comment: Also, if you don't have any TemplateResolver, i believe it would of have been "templates/index.html".