# Error resolving template - url mapping fails

Tags: rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I receive the following error message:

> Error resolving template [catalog/getCatalogItemFromCatalog/catalogItemId/3916677], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I am trying to reach my service and the method using this url:

```
 http://192.168.99.100:31003/catalog/getCatalogItemFromCatalog/catalogItemId/3916677
```

> Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("catalog")
public class CatalogController {

    @GetMapping("/getCatalogItemFromCatalog/catalogItemId/{catalogItemId}")
    public CatalogItem getCatalogItemFromCatalog(@PathVariable Integer catalogItemId){
        List<Catalog> catalogs = getAllCatalogs();
        Optional<CatalogItem> optionalCatalogItem = Optional.empty();
        for(Catalog catalog : catalogs){
            optionalCatalogItem = catalog.getCatalogItems().stream().filter(it -> it.getCatalogItemId().equals(catalogItemId)).findFirst();
        }
        return optionalCatalogItem.orElse(null);
    }

    @GetMapping("/system/ipaddr")
    public String getIpAddr() {
        List<String> response;
        response = runSystemCommandAndGetResponse(IP_ADDR);
        return new Gson().toJson(response);
    }
}
```

When I curl

```
http://192.168.99.100:31003/catalog/system/ipaddr
```

I have no issues.
I am testing for hours now and nothing seems to work, I have no idea why its failing tho.

Comment: try to adding and slash / @RequestMapping("/catalog") let me know what happens

Comment: I think I just figured out.. I have no idea why, but `return optionalCatalogItem.orElse(null);` seems to trigger a thymeleaf template. The url mapping works fine, the error message is confusing tho..
Gonna confirm this in a minute.

Comment: Okay then perhaps this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944355/error-resolving-template-index-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be-acces helps you

Comment: Uhm, this is a little bit weird. But after adding `@ResponseBody` its working.... Someone can explain this to me?

Comment: Then if you put @RestController instead of Controller.. should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `@Controller` on your class which means spring will try to resolve the return type of all your methods inside the controller using all the available templateResolvers.

by using `@ResponseBody` spring will wrap the return type inside the response (after converting it) directly then returns it to the client, it's similar to using `@RestController` instead `@Controller`

Comment: Now I understand why it's called `Rest`Client ;D Because it's working for clients requesting the data via rest.... :facepalm: Jesus, this took me years xd